# FFMPEG build on Windows using MSVC - make fails

Tags: awk, makefile, ffmpeg, mingw, mingw32

I am trying to build FFMPEG on Windows with MSVC. I am following this [guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MSVC).
I have managed to setup the environment in order to configure successfully, but make doesn't work.
From VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt I run

```
msys2_shell.cmd -use-full-path
```

and from msys2_shell.cmd I go to the ffmpeg folder and run

```
mingw32-make
```

which outputs:

```
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                        ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: /including/ { sub(/^.*file: */, ""); gsub(/\/, "/"); if (!match($0, / /)) print "libavdevice/alldevices.o:", $0 }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                           ^ unterminated string
ffbuild/common.mak:67: recipe for target 'libavdevice/alldevices.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [libavdevice/alldevices.o] Error 1
```

Some more info:

```
$ mingw32-make --version
GNU Make 3.82.90
Built for i686-pc-mingw32
Copyright (C) 1988-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

FFMPEG snapshot version N-100459-ga7f9b3b
The Makefile:

```
MAIN_MAKEFILE=1
include ffbuild/config.mak

vpath %.c    $(SRC_PATH)
vpath %.cpp  $(SRC_PATH)
vpath %.h    $(SRC_PATH)
vpath %.inc  $(SRC_PATH)
vpath %.m    $(SRC_PATH)
vpath %.S    $(SRC_PATH)
vpath %.asm  $(SRC_PATH)
vpath %.rc   $(SRC_PATH)
vpath %.v    $(SRC_PATH)
vpath %.texi $(SRC_PATH)
vpath %.cu   $(SRC_PATH)
vpath %.ptx  $(SRC_PATH)
vpath %/fate_config.sh.template $(SRC_PATH)

TESTTOOLS   = audiogen videogen rotozoom tiny_psnr tiny_ssim base64 audiomatch
HOSTPROGS  := $(TESTTOOLS:%=tests/%) doc/print_options

# $(FFLIBS-yes) needs to be in linking order
FFLIBS-$(CONFIG_AVDEVICE)   += avdevice
FFLIBS-$(CONFIG_AVFILTER)   += avfilter
FFLIBS-$(CONFIG_AVFORMAT)   += avformat
FFLIBS-$(CONFIG_AVCODEC)    += avcodec
FFLIBS-$(CONFIG_AVRESAMPLE) += avresample
FFLIBS-$(CONFIG_POSTPROC)   += postproc
FFLIBS-$(CONFIG_SWRESAMPLE) += swresample
FFLIBS-$(CONFIG_SWSCALE)    += swscale

FFLIBS := avutil

DATA_FILES := $(wildcard $(SRC_PATH)/presets/*.ffpreset) $(SRC_PATH)/doc/ffprobe.xsd

SKIPHEADERS = compat/w32pthreads.h

# first so "all" becomes default target
all: all-yes

include $(SRC_PATH)/tools/Makefile
include $(SRC_PATH)/ffbuild/common.mak

FF_EXTRALIBS := $(FFEXTRALIBS)
FF_DEP_LIBS  := $(DEP_LIBS)
FF_STATIC_DEP_LIBS := $(STATIC_DEP_LIBS)

$(TOOLS): %$(EXESUF): %.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDEXEFLAGS) $(LD_O) $^ $(EXTRALIBS-$(*F)) $(EXTRALIBS) $(ELIBS)

target_dec_%_fuzzer$(EXESUF): target_dec_%_fuzzer.o $(FF_DEP_LIBS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDEXEFLAGS) $(LD_O) $^ $(ELIBS) $(FF_EXTRALIBS) $(LIBFUZZER_PATH)

tools/target_bsf_%_fuzzer$(EXESUF): tools/target_bsf_%_fuzzer.o $(FF_DEP_LIBS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDEXEFLAGS) $(LD_O) $^ $(ELIBS) $(FF_EXTRALIBS) $(LIBFUZZER_PATH)

target_dem_%_fuzzer$(EXESUF): target_dem_%_fuzzer.o $(FF_DEP_LIBS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDEXEFLAGS) $(LD_O) $^ $(ELIBS) $(FF_EXTRALIBS) $(LIBFUZZER_PATH)

tools/target_dem_fuzzer$(EXESUF): tools/target_dem_fuzzer.o $(FF_DEP_LIBS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDEXEFLAGS) $(LD_O) $^ $(ELIBS) $(FF_EXTRALIBS) $(LIBFUZZER_PATH)

tools/target_io_dem_fuzzer$(EXESUF): tools/target_io_dem_fuzzer.o $(FF_DEP_LIBS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDEXEFLAGS) $(LD_O) $^ $(ELIBS) $(FF_EXTRALIBS) $(LIBFUZZER_PATH)


tools/enum_options$(EXESUF): ELIBS = $(FF_EXTRALIBS)
tools/enum_options$(EXESUF): $(FF_DEP_LIBS)
tools/sofa2wavs$(EXESUF): ELIBS = $(FF_EXTRALIBS)
tools/uncoded_frame$(EXESUF): $(FF_DEP_LIBS)
tools/uncoded_frame$(EXESUF): ELIBS = $(FF_EXTRALIBS)
tools/target_dec_%_fuzzer$(EXESUF): $(FF_DEP_LIBS)
tools/target_dem_%_fuzzer$(EXESUF): $(FF_DEP_LIBS)

CONFIGURABLE_COMPONENTS =                                           \
    $(wildcard $(FFLIBS:%=$(SRC_PATH)/lib%/all*.c))                 \
    $(SRC_PATH)/libavcodec/bitstream_filters.c                      \
    $(SRC_PATH)/libavcodec/parsers.c                                \
    $(SRC_PATH)/libavformat/protocols.c                             \

config.h: ffbuild/.config
ffbuild/.config: $(CONFIGURABLE_COMPONENTS)
    @-tput bold 2>/dev/null
    @-printf '\nWARNING: $(?) newer than config.h, rerun configure\n\n'
    @-tput sgr0 2>/dev/null

SUBDIR_VARS := CLEANFILES FFLIBS HOSTPROGS TESTPROGS TOOLS               \
               HEADERS ARCH_HEADERS BUILT_HEADERS SKIPHEADERS            \
               ARMV5TE-OBJS ARMV6-OBJS ARMV8-OBJS VFP-OBJS NEON-OBJS     \
               ALTIVEC-OBJS VSX-OBJS MMX-OBJS X86ASM-OBJS                \
               MIPSFPU-OBJS MIPSDSPR2-OBJS MIPSDSP-OBJS MSA-OBJS         \
               MMI-OBJS OBJS SLIBOBJS HOSTOBJS TESTOBJS

define RESET
$(1) :=
$(1)-yes :=
endef

define DOSUBDIR
$(foreach V,$(SUBDIR_VARS),$(eval $(call RESET,$(V))))
SUBDIR := $(1)/
include $(SRC_PATH)/$(1)/Makefile
-include $(SRC_PATH)/$(1)/$(ARCH)/Makefile
-include $(SRC_PATH)/$(1)/$(INTRINSICS)/Makefile
include $(SRC_PATH)/ffbuild/library.mak
endef

$(foreach D,$(FFLIBS),$(eval $(call DOSUBDIR,lib$(D))))

include $(SRC_PATH)/fftools/Makefile
include $(SRC_PATH)/doc/Makefile
include $(SRC_PATH)/doc/examples/Makefile

libavcodec/utils.o libavformat/utils.o libavdevice/avdevice.o libavfilter/avfilter.o libavutil/utils.o libpostproc/postprocess.o libswresample/swresample.o libswscale/utils.o : libavutil/ffversion.h

$(PROGS): %$(PROGSSUF)$(EXESUF): %$(PROGSSUF)_g$(EXESUF)
ifeq ($(STRIPTYPE),direct)
    $(STRIP) -o $@ $<
else
    $(CP) $< $@
    $(STRIP) $@
endif

%$(PROGSSUF)_g$(EXESUF): $(FF_DEP_LIBS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDEXEFLAGS) $(LD_O) $(OBJS-$*) $(FF_EXTRALIBS)

VERSION_SH  = $(SRC_PATH)/ffbuild/version.sh
GIT_LOG     = $(SRC_PATH)/.git/logs/HEAD

.version: $(wildcard $(GIT_LOG)) $(VERSION_SH) ffbuild/config.mak
.version: M=@

libavutil/ffversion.h .version:
    $(M)$(VERSION_SH) $(SRC_PATH) libavutil/ffversion.h $(EXTRA_VERSION)
    $(Q)touch .version

# force version.sh to run whenever version might have changed
-include .version

install: install-libs install-headers

install-libs: install-libs-yes

install-data: $(DATA_FILES)
    $(Q)mkdir -p "$(DATADIR)"
    $(INSTALL) -m 644 $(DATA_FILES) "$(DATADIR)"

uninstall: uninstall-data uninstall-headers uninstall-libs uninstall-pkgconfig

uninstall-data:
    $(RM) -r "$(DATADIR)"

clean::
    $(RM) $(CLEANSUFFIXES)
    $(RM) $(addprefix compat/,$(CLEANSUFFIXES)) $(addprefix compat/*/,$(CLEANSUFFIXES)) $(addprefix compat/*/*/,$(CLEANSUFFIXES))
    $(RM) -r coverage-html
    $(RM) -rf coverage.info coverage.info.in lcov

distclean:: clean
    $(RM) .version avversion.h config.asm config.h mapfile  \
        ffbuild/.config ffbuild/config.* libavutil/avconfig.h \
        version.h libavutil/ffversion.h libavcodec/codec_names.h \
        libavcodec/bsf_list.c libavformat/protocol_list.c \
        libavcodec/codec_list.c libavcodec/parser_list.c \
        libavfilter/filter_list.c libavdevice/indev_list.c libavdevice/outdev_list.c \
        libavformat/muxer_list.c libavformat/demuxer_list.c
ifeq ($(SRC_LINK),src)
    $(RM) src
endif
    $(RM) -rf doc/examples/pc-uninstalled

config:
    $(SRC_PATH)/configure $(value FFMPEG_CONFIGURATION)

build: all alltools examples testprogs
check: all alltools examples testprogs fate

include $(SRC_PATH)/tests/Makefile

$(sort $(OUTDIRS)):
    $(Q)mkdir -p $@

# Dummy rule to stop make trying to rebuild removed or renamed headers
%.h:
    @:

# Disable suffix rules.  Most of the builtin rules are suffix rules,
# so this saves some time on slow systems.
.SUFFIXES:

.PHONY: all all-yes alltools build check config testprogs
.PHONY: *clean install* uninstall*
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

**EDIT**
Tried starting with x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019 and got the same result.

**EDIT #2** (because this is too long for a comment)

```
$ mingw32-make Q=
mkdir -p libavutil/
mkdir -p libswscale/
mkdir -p libswresample/
mkdir -p libavcodec/
mkdir -p libavformat/
mkdir -p libavfilter/
mkdir -p libavdevice/
awk: cmd. line:1: /including/ { sub(/^.*file: */, ""); gsub(/\/, "/"); if (!match($0, / /)) print "libavdevice/alldevices.o:", $0 }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                        ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: /including/ { sub(/^.*file: */, ""); gsub(/\/, "/"); if (!match($0, / /)) print "libavdevice/alldevices.o:", $0 }
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                                                                           ^ unterminated string
ffbuild/common.mak:67: recipe for target 'libavdevice/alldevices.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [libavdevice/alldevices.o] Error 1
```

`ffbuild/common.mak` is:

```
#
# common bits used by all libraries
#

DEFAULT_X86ASMD=.dbg

ifeq ($(DBG),1)
X86ASMD=$(DEFAULT_X86ASMD)
else
X86ASMD=
endif

ifndef SUBDIR

ifndef V
Q      = @
ECHO   = printf "$(1)\t%s\n" $(2)
BRIEF  = CC CXX OBJCC HOSTCC HOSTLD AS X86ASM AR LD STRIP CP WINDRES NVCC
SILENT = DEPCC DEPHOSTCC DEPAS DEPX86ASM RANLIB RM

MSG    = $@
M      = @$(call ECHO,$(TAG),$@);
$(foreach VAR,$(BRIEF), \
    $(eval override $(VAR) = @$$(call ECHO,$(VAR),$$(MSG)); $($(VAR))))
$(foreach VAR,$(SILENT),$(eval override $(VAR) = @$($(VAR))))
$(eval INSTALL = @$(call ECHO,INSTALL,$$(^:$(SRC_DIR)/%=%)); $(INSTALL))
endif

ALLFFLIBS = avcodec avdevice avfilter avformat avresample avutil postproc swscale swresample

# NASM requires -I path terminated with /
IFLAGS     := -I. -I$(SRC_LINK)/
CPPFLAGS   := $(IFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)
CFLAGS     += $(ECFLAGS)
CCFLAGS     = $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)
OBJCFLAGS  += $(EOBJCFLAGS)
OBJCCFLAGS  = $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJCFLAGS)
ASFLAGS    := $(CPPFLAGS) $(ASFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS   := $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS)
X86ASMFLAGS += $(IFLAGS:%=%/) -I$(<D)/ -Pconfig.asm

HOSTCCFLAGS = $(IFLAGS) $(HOSTCPPFLAGS) $(HOSTCFLAGS)
LDFLAGS    := $(ALLFFLIBS:%=$(LD_PATH)lib%) $(LDFLAGS)

define COMPILE
       $(call $(1)DEP,$(1))
       $($(1)) $($(1)FLAGS) $($(2)) $($(1)_DEPFLAGS) $($(1)_C) $($(1)_O) $(patsubst $(SRC_PATH)/%,$(SRC_LINK)/%,$<)
endef

COMPILE_C = $(call COMPILE,CC)
COMPILE_CXX = $(call COMPILE,CXX)
COMPILE_S = $(call COMPILE,AS)
COMPILE_M = $(call COMPILE,OBJCC)
COMPILE_X86ASM = $(call COMPILE,X86ASM)
COMPILE_HOSTC = $(call COMPILE,HOSTCC)
COMPILE_NVCC = $(call COMPILE,NVCC)
COMPILE_MMI = $(call COMPILE,CC,MMIFLAGS)
COMPILE_MSA = $(call COMPILE,CC,MSAFLAGS)

%_mmi.o: %_mmi.c
    $(COMPILE_MMI)

%_msa.o: %_msa.c
    $(COMPILE_MSA)

%.o: %.c
    $(COMPILE_C)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(COMPILE_CXX)

%.o: %.m
    $(COMPILE_M)

%.s: %.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -S -o $@ $<

%.o: %.S
    $(COMPILE_S)

%_host.o: %.c
    $(COMPILE_HOSTC)

%$(DEFAULT_X86ASMD).asm: %.asm
    $(DEPX86ASM) $(X86ASMFLAGS) -M -o $@ $< > $(@:.asm=.d)
    $(X86ASM) $(X86ASMFLAGS) -e $< | sed '/^%/d;/^$$/d;' > $@

%.o: %.asm
    $(COMPILE_X86ASM)
    -$(if $(ASMSTRIPFLAGS), $(STRIP) $(ASMSTRIPFLAGS) $@)

%.o: %.rc
    $(WINDRES) $(IFLAGS) --preprocessor "$(DEPWINDRES) -E -xc-header -DRC_INVOKED $(CC_DEPFLAGS)" -o $@ $<

%.i: %.c
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(CC_E) $<

%.h.c:
    $(Q)echo '#include "$*.h"' >$@

%.ptx: %.cu $(SRC_PATH)/compat/cuda/cuda_runtime.h
    $(COMPILE_NVCC)

%.ptx.c: %.ptx
    $(Q)sh $(SRC_PATH)/compat/cuda/ptx2c.sh $@ $(patsubst $(SRC_PATH)/%,$(SRC_LINK)/%,$<)

%.c %.h %.pc %.ver %.version: TAG = GEN

# Dummy rule to stop make trying to rebuild removed or renamed headers
%.h:
    @:

# Disable suffix rules.  Most of the builtin rules are suffix rules,
# so this saves some time on slow systems.
.SUFFIXES:

# Do not delete intermediate files from chains of implicit rules
$(OBJS):
endif

include $(SRC_PATH)/ffbuild/arch.mak

OBJS      += $(OBJS-yes)
SLIBOBJS  += $(SLIBOBJS-yes)
FFLIBS    := $($(NAME)_FFLIBS) $(FFLIBS-yes) $(FFLIBS)
TESTPROGS += $(TESTPROGS-yes)

LDLIBS       = $(FFLIBS:%=%$(BUILDSUF))
FFEXTRALIBS := $(LDLIBS:%=$(LD_LIB)) $(foreach lib,EXTRALIBS-$(NAME) $(FFLIBS:%=EXTRALIBS-%),$($(lib))) $(EXTRALIBS)

OBJS      := $(sort $(OBJS:%=$(SUBDIR)%))
SLIBOBJS  := $(sort $(SLIBOBJS:%=$(SUBDIR)%))
TESTOBJS  := $(TESTOBJS:%=$(SUBDIR)tests/%) $(TESTPROGS:%=$(SUBDIR)tests/%.o)
TESTPROGS := $(TESTPROGS:%=$(SUBDIR)tests/%$(EXESUF))
HOSTOBJS  := $(HOSTPROGS:%=$(SUBDIR)%.o)
HOSTPROGS := $(HOSTPROGS:%=$(SUBDIR)%$(HOSTEXESUF))
TOOLS     += $(TOOLS-yes)
TOOLOBJS  := $(TOOLS:%=tools/%.o)
TOOLS     := $(TOOLS:%=tools/%$(EXESUF))
HEADERS   += $(HEADERS-yes)

PATH_LIBNAME = $(foreach NAME,$(1),lib$(NAME)/$($(2)LIBNAME))
DEP_LIBS := $(foreach lib,$(FFLIBS),$(call PATH_LIBNAME,$(lib),$(CONFIG_SHARED:yes=S)))
STATIC_DEP_LIBS := $(foreach lib,$(FFLIBS),$(call PATH_LIBNAME,$(lib)))

SRC_DIR    := $(SRC_PATH)/lib$(NAME)
ALLHEADERS := $(subst $(SRC_DIR)/,$(SUBDIR),$(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.h $(SRC_DIR)/$(ARCH)/*.h))
SKIPHEADERS += $(ARCH_HEADERS:%=$(ARCH)/%) $(SKIPHEADERS-)
SKIPHEADERS := $(SKIPHEADERS:%=$(SUBDIR)%)
HOBJS        = $(filter-out $(SKIPHEADERS:.h=.h.o),$(ALLHEADERS:.h=.h.o))
PTXOBJS      = $(filter %.ptx.o,$(OBJS))
$(HOBJS):     CCFLAGS += $(CFLAGS_HEADERS)
checkheaders: $(HOBJS)
.SECONDARY:   $(HOBJS:.o=.c) $(PTXOBJS:.o=.c) $(PTXOBJS:.o=)

alltools: $(TOOLS)

$(HOSTOBJS): %.o: %.c
    $(COMPILE_HOSTC)

$(HOSTPROGS): %$(HOSTEXESUF): %.o
    $(HOSTLD) $(HOSTLDFLAGS) $(HOSTLD_O) $^ $(HOSTEXTRALIBS)

$(OBJS):     | $(sort $(dir $(OBJS)))
$(HOBJS):    | $(sort $(dir $(HOBJS)))
$(HOSTOBJS): | $(sort $(dir $(HOSTOBJS)))
$(SLIBOBJS): | $(sort $(dir $(SLIBOBJS)))
$(TESTOBJS): | $(sort $(dir $(TESTOBJS)))
$(TOOLOBJS): | tools

OUTDIRS := $(OUTDIRS) $(dir $(OBJS) $(HOBJS) $(HOSTOBJS) $(SLIBOBJS) $(TESTOBJS))

CLEANSUFFIXES     = *.d *.gcda *.gcno *.h.c *.ho *.map *.o *.pc *.ptx *.ptx.c *.ver *.version *$(DEFAULT_X86ASMD).asm *~ *.ilk *.pdb
LIBSUFFIXES       = *.a *.lib *.so *.so.* *.dylib *.dll *.def *.dll.a

define RULES
clean::
    $(RM) $(HOSTPROGS) $(TESTPROGS) $(TOOLS)
endef

$(eval $(RULES))

-include $(wildcard $(OBJS:.o=.d) $(HOSTOBJS:.o=.d) $(TESTOBJS:.o=.d) $(HOBJS:.o=.d) $(SLIBOBJS:.o=.d)) $(OBJS:.o=$(DEFAULT_X86ASMD).d)
```

Comment: The error message says `ffbuild/common.mak:67: ...` so what is the rule at line 67 of the file `ffbuild/common.mak` ?  Also when showing error messages, please always include the command that was invoked before the errors and at least the first few error messages: the last error messages are often not very interesting as they can just be cascading errors... the first error is usually the most interesting one.

Comment: Line 67 in ```ffbuild/common.mak``` is simply  ```$(COMPILE_C)```. The error messages I mentioned in the question are all that was printed following ```mingw32-make```

Comment: That can't be all that was printed, since the first line you show is referring to a line before it that you don't show.  To know what's happening you'll have to find out more than that.  You'll have to know what the `COMPILE_C` variable expands to.  You might also try adding the `Q=` option to your make command line, based on the makefile part you've shown that might display more output.  Else, someone familiar with ffmpeg and its makefiles will have to help.

Comment: Just in case it matters, if you haven't done so I strongly recommend you ensure that none of the directories in the path containing the source you're trying to build contains any spaces.

Comment: the path is ```C:\msys64\home\admin\ffmpeg``` . no spaces

Comment: Well, that still didn't show the command line.  Sorry, I can't help so you'll have to debug it yourself or find someone who knows about ffmpeg builds on Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I found another [guide](https://www.roxlu.com/2019/062/compiling-ffmpeg-with-x264-on-windows-10-using-msvc) that did the trick. Hopes this helps others. Happy new year :)

Comment: I encountered the same issue with standard ffmpeg build instructions as of April 4th, 2021. Following the instructions from the guide in this answer worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Seems the `make` is culprit here. I had to install `make` using `pacman -S make` command to overcome this issue.